# mysql query if value is empty

Tags: mysql

I want to query out the first 20 results if `category='art'` and there is no value in `image` field.

Can I write an SQL query like this?

```
SELECT image,date,category FROM imagecart WHERE category='art' AND image != '' Order By date DESC LIMIT 0,20
```

Comment: That looks right, but depending on how "no image" is stored in your system, you may need `...AND Image IS NULL ORDER BY...` instead.  Your questions asks for "no value" but your query is filtering for "image is NOT empty"; which do you need?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alternatively:

```
SELECT image,date,category 
FROM imagecart 
WHERE category='art' 
AND LENGTH(image) = 0 
ORDER BY  date DESC LIMIT 0,20
```

Modify as you need to check for nulls:

```
AND (LENGTH(image) = 0 OR image IS NULL)
```